# Random non repeating card array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am making a game of war between the player and the computer. When I click the deal button, an array gets shuffled for each player. When the play button is clicked, the array of cards show up in the div as images. The problem I am running in to is that the cards are being repeated, and I need help on how to make them not repeated. Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById('play').disabled = true;

  function card(name, suit, value, trump) {
    this.name = name;
    this.suit = suit;
    this.value = value;
    this.trump = trump;
  }

  var deck = [
    new card('Ace', 'Hearts', 11, 142),
    new card('Two', 'Hearts', 2, 22),
    new card('Three', 'Hearts', 3, 32),
    new card('Four', 'Hearts', 4, 42),
    new card('Five', 'Hearts', 5, 52),
    new card('Six', 'Hearts', 6, 62),
    new card('Seven', 'Hearts', 7, 72),
    new card('Eight', 'Hearts', 8, 82),
    new card('Nine', 'Hearts', 9, 92),
    new card('Ten', 'Hearts', 10, 102),
    new card('Jack', 'Hearts', 10, 112),
    new card('Queen', 'Hearts', 10, 122),
    new card('King', 'Hearts', 10, 132),
    new card('Ace', 'Diamonds', 11, 141),
    new card('Two', 'Diamonds', 2, 21),
    new card('Three', 'Diamonds', 3, 31),
    new card('Four', 'Diamonds', 4, 41),
    new card('Five', 'Diamonds', 5, 51),
    new card('Six', 'Diamonds', 6, 61),
    new card('Seven', 'Diamonds', 7, 71),
    new card('Eight', 'Diamonds', 8, 81),
    new card('Nine', 'Diamonds', 9, 91),
    new card('Ten', 'Diamonds', 10, 101),
    new card('Jack', 'Diamonds', 10, 111),
    new card('Queen', 'Diamonds', 10, 121),
    new card('King', 'Diamonds', 10, 131),
    new card('Ace', 'Clubs', 11, 143),
    new card('Two', 'Clubs', 2, 23),
    new card('Three', 'Clubs', 3, 33),
    new card('Four', 'Clubs', 4, 43),
    new card('Five', 'Clubs', 5, 53),
    new card('Six', 'Clubs', 6, 63),
    new card('Seven', 'Clubs', 7, 73),
    new card('Eight', 'Clubs', 8, 83),
    new card('Nine', 'Clubs', 9, 93),
    new card('Ten', 'Clubs', 10, 103),
    new card('Jack', 'Clubs', 10, 113),
    new card('Queen', 'Clubs', 10, 123),
    new card('King', 'Clubs', 10, 133),
    new card('Ace', 'Spades', 11, 144),
    new card('Two', 'Spades', 2, 24),
    new card('Three', 'Spades', 3, 34),
    new card('Four', 'Spades', 4, 44),
    new card('Five', 'Spades', 5, 54),
    new card('Six', 'Spades', 6, 64),
    new card('Seven', 'Spades', 7, 74),
    new card('Eight', 'Spades', 8, 84),
    new card('Nine', 'Spades', 9, 94),
    new card('Ten', 'Spades', 10, 104),
    new card('Jack', 'Spades', 10, 114),
    new card('Queen', 'Spades', 10, 124),
    new card('King', 'Spades', 10, 134)
  ];

  // var test = '!$.inArray(index, used_cards) > -1';
  // console.log('test ' + test);

  var used_cards = new Array();

  // var pTotal = 0;
  // pTotal = pTotal + deck[num1].value + deck[num2].value;

  function getRandom(num) {
    var my_num = Math.floor(Math.random() *num);
    return my_num;
  }

  function playerHit() {
    var good_player_card = false;
    do{
      var index = getRandom(52);
      if ( !$.inArray(index, used_cards) > -1) {
        good_player_card = true;
        var c = deck[index];
        used_cards[used_cards.length] = index;
        $("<img>")
        .attr('src', 'images/' + c.suit + '/' + c.name + '.jpg')
        .appendTo('#pHand')
        .fadeIn('1000');
      }
    }while (!good_player_card);
    good_player_card = false;
  }

  function slickHit() {

    var good_slick_card = false;
    do{
      var index = getRandom(52);
      if ( !$.inArray(index, used_cards) > -1) {
        good_slick_card = true;
        var c = deck[index];
        used_cards[used_cards.length] = index;
        $("<img>")
        .attr('src', 'images/' + c.suit + '/' + c.name + '.jpg')
        .appendTo('#cHand')
        .fadeIn('1500');
      }
    }while (!good_slick_card);
    good_slick_card = false;
  }

  /* function slickHit() {
  var index = getRandom)(52)

  $.inArray(index)

} */

$('#deal').one('click', function(){
  var player = prompt("Please enter your name.")
  if (player != null) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("pName")[0].innerHTML = player;
    document.getElementsByClassName("pName")[1].innerHTML = player;
  }

  document.getElementById('play').disabled = false;

  let card_count = 26;
  $('#cardCount').innerHTML = card_count;
});

$('#play').click(function(){
  $('img').remove();
  playerHit();
  slickHit();
});

$("#newPlayer").click(function(){
  var newPlayer = prompt("Please enter your name.")
  if (newPlayer != null) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("pName")[0].innerHTML = newPlayer;
    document.getElementsByClassName("pName")[1].innerHTML = newPlayer;
  }
  playerHit();
  slickHit();
  $('img').remove();
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Card Game</title>
    <link href="styles/normalilze.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1> Card Game </h1>
        <div id="left">

            <div id="pHand">
                <br />
                <!-- Using JavaScript replace the word 'Player' with the name of
            the person playing the game-->
                <h2 class="pName">Player</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="cHand">
                <h2>Slick</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="but">
                <button id="newPlayer">New player</button>
                <button id="deal">Deal</button>
                <button id="play">Play</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id='right'>
            <h2>Card Count:</h2>
            <!-- Using JavaSCript enter the number of remaining cards in the 'Players' hand
            in the p tag below-->
            <p id="cardCount"></p>
            <br />
            <!-- Using JavaSCript replace the word 'Player' with the name of
            the person playing the game-->
            <h2 class="pName">Player</h2>
            <h2 id="pName2">:</h2>
            <!-- Using jQuery insert the current 'Player' score in the p tag
             below -->
            <p id="pScore"></p>
            <br />
            <h2 id="cName">Slick:</h2>
            <!-- Using jQuery insert the current 'Slick' score in the p tag
             below -->
            <p id="cScore"></p>

            <!-- add and style winning message in the
             following div -->
            <div id="win"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jQ-War.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Don't create 52 random indices into your deck of cards. Just walk through the array of cards and swap each one with another chose at random.

Comment: What would that look like? I am fairly new to arrays.

Comment: your `deck` variable is an array. I'll post an example.

Answer (score 0):

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt)
{
    method1();
    console.log('----------');
    method2();
}

class cardT
{
    constructor(name, suit, value, trump)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
        this.trump = trump;
    }
}

function method1()
{
    // Method 1, yours
    var cards = [
        new cardT('Ace', 'Hearts', 11, 142),
        new cardT('Two', 'Hearts', 2, 22),
        new cardT('Three', 'Hearts', 3, 32),
        new cardT('Four', 'Hearts', 4, 42),
        new cardT('Five', 'Hearts', 5, 52),
        new cardT('Six', 'Hearts', 6, 62),
        new cardT('Seven', 'Hearts', 7, 72),
        new cardT('Eight', 'Hearts', 8, 82),
        new cardT('Nine', 'Hearts', 9, 92),
        new cardT('Ten', 'Hearts', 10, 102),
    ];
    // keep record of the randomly chosen indices
    var indices = [];
    for (var i=0; i<cards.length; i++)
    {
        let curIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*cards.length);
        indices.push(curIndex);
        console.log( cards[curIndex].name, cards[curIndex].suit );
    }
    console.log(indices);
}

function method2()
{
    var cards = [
        new cardT('Ace', 'Hearts', 11, 142),
        new cardT('Two', 'Hearts', 2, 22),
        new cardT('Three', 'Hearts', 3, 32),
        new cardT('Four', 'Hearts', 4, 42),
        new cardT('Five', 'Hearts', 5, 52),
        new cardT('Six', 'Hearts', 6, 62),
        new cardT('Seven', 'Hearts', 7, 72),
        new cardT('Eight', 'Hearts', 8, 82),
        new cardT('Nine', 'Hearts', 9, 92),
        new cardT('Ten', 'Hearts', 10, 102),
    ];
    
    for (var index=0; index<cards.length; index++)
    {
        // pick a position at random
        var randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*cards.length);
        
        // swap the current card with the randomly chosen one
        var tmp = cards[index];
        cards[index] = cards[randIndex];
        cards[randIndex] = tmp;
    }
    // display them all
    for (var i=0; i<cards.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(cards[i].name, cards[i].suit);
    }
}
```